# Could not copy. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

I am getting the following error when running my build on Visual Studio Online (using the built-in Build Controller):

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>   (3962): Could not copy
>   "d:\a\src\MySolution\MyProject\Trunk\packages\Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.6.4\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.Edm.xml"
>   to "..\Build\bin\Release\Microsoft.Data.Edm.xml". Beginning retry 1 in
>   1000ms. The process cannot access the file
>   '..\Build\bin\Release\Microsoft.Data.Edm.xml' because it is being used
>   by another process.

It is never the same file either but it seems to always be either an xml or dll from the packages folder.

**EDIT:** I'm not sure if it is worth mentioning, but I do have multiple workspaces and multiple build definitions using this repository.

Comment: Try passing the MSbuild argument /m:1 to reduce the number of processors used to build to 1.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is worth mentioning, but I do have multiple workspaces and multiple build definitions using this repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. Completely unrelated to the error above.

I went into the msbuild log files and found this:

> Failed to produce diagnostics extension's config for
>   MyRole\diagnostics.wadcfgx. Error : Could not find a part of the path
>   'd:\a\src...\MyRole\diagnostics.wadcfgx'. Done Building Project
>   "d:\a\src...\MyCloudProject.Cloud.ccproj" (Publish target(s)) --
>   FAILED.

I was missing a file in source control.

I do wonder why this error did not bubble up into my build summary.  And where did that initial error come from?

Comment: Where do you find the log file?

Answer (score 1):

I am using TFS with Using Visual Studio 2013 and have been able to work around this issue by closing all open documents that I want to check-in (seems VS locked itself out) and/or resolving conflicts.  The error message is sufficiently vague so as to be useless as to the actual cause of the check-in failure.

Update 02 November 2016:

I'm not sure why VS 2013 and TFS don't play nice together via the Team Explorer Check-in Pending Changes button, but it consistently fails to launch the conflict resolver, a key piece of the check-in process.

The following works for me on VS 2013 and TFS hosted on a SQLServer Express 2014 database:
1. Launch the Source Explorer: Team Explorer tab -> Source Explorer
2. Navigate to your solution repository
3. Then proceed to do the following for each project that you want to check in:
  a. Right click project
  b. Check in pending changes
  c. Resolve conflicts and repeat steps 3a and 3b until no pending changes remain for the project